Find a necessary and sufficient condition on $a$ which ensures that $\{f_k\}$ converges pointwise $m$-a.e.
Consider the Lebesgue measure space $([0,1], \mathcal{M}([0,1]), m)$. Let $a>0$ and let $\{f_k:k\in\mathbb{N}\}$ be a sequence of Lebesgue measurable functions $f_k:[0,1]\to [0,\infty)$ such that $$\int_0^1 f_k\le \frac{1}{k^a}$$
Find a necessary and sufficient condition on $a$ which ensures that $\{f_k\}$ converges pointwise $m$-a.e.

For $a>1$, by monotone convergence theorem we have
$$
\int \sum_{k=1}^\infty f_k=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\int f_k\le \sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{1}{k^a}<\infty
$$
So we have
$$
\sum_{k=1}^\infty f_k<\infty a.e.
$$
Hence, $\lim_{k\to\infty} f_k=0$ a.e.
But for $0<a\le 1$, how do we do that "use characteristic functions of intervals of length less than $1/k^a$ which cover $[0,1]$ infinitely many times"? Use Borel-Cantelli Lemma?
